# VBScript Split Large excel file into smaller File after every 50,000 rows

Tags: vbscript, excel-2010

I have been asked to split a very large excel file 1,000,000+ rows into smaller excel
files after a certain number of rows that the user decides via an inputBox, but before this is to happen I have to ask the user if they would like to replace specfic columns with "#####" using another inputBox once the info for the columns has been stored to a variable userCensor, then I would like to take the number that was entered for the row split, store it as userSplit and split the file at the interval specified in userSplit.

This is what I have so far and I am currently experienceing a major brain fart and don't know where to go from here:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("Y:\BLAHBLAHBLAH").Files  
If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "xls" Then
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)

set sh = wb.Sheets("Sheet 1") row = 1 
lastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count 
lastColumn = sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count 
strRow = lastRow 
userSplit = InputBox("Enter when you want to split between 1 - " + strRow) 
strColumn = lastColumn 
userCensor = InputBox("Enter Columns to censor (Format example: 'A:A' deletes column A) Between 1 - " + strColumn)

If userCensor.IsNumeric Then Columns(userCensor).Select
    Selection.Replace("######")

For r = row to LastRow If lastColumn > 1 Then




Else
```

It isn't much to go off but any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this for dividing the content into smaller parts:

```
firstRow  = ws.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row
lastRow   = ws.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
userSplit = CLng(InputBox("Enter when you want to split between 1 - " _
            & lastRow-firstRow+1))

n = 0
For srcRow = firstrow To lastrow
  dstRow = (srcRow - firstRow) Mod userSplit + 1
  If dstRow = 1 Then
    n = (srcRow - firstRow) \ userSplit
    If n > 0 Then
      wb2.SaveAs "C:\path\to\out" & n & ".xls"
      wb2.Close
    End If
    Set wb2 = xl.Workbooks.Add
  End If
  ws1.Cells(srcRow, 1).EntireRow.Copy
  wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(dstRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlAll
Next
wb2.SaveAs "C:\path\to\out" & (lastRow - firstRow) \ userSplit & ".xls"
wb2.Close
```

As for deleting columns, wouldn't it be easier to actually delete the columns instead of replacing their content with something else?